# What is the best mage talent tree for raiding in patch 4.2?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm wondering what people consider to be the best mage talent tree for single target 5 man heroic and raid dps in WoW 4.2 and why? TIA

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what features you're looking for in this spec? Are you just worried about sheer DPS, or are there other important factors? Without a little more detail, this question comes across as a rather open-ended opinion poll and is likely to be closed.

Comment: @sjohnston Generally speaking, if someone asks about a tree 'for raiding', one can assume that they're asking for the highest single target DPS spec unless the 'intangibles' of an alternative are absolutely massive. There's a reason cookie cutter specs are cookie cutter at the top end!

Comment: @LessPop - I realize that, I was just hoping the OP could be a little more explicit about those expectations.

Comment: Sorry I'm primarily interested in single target dps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boss fights is the only thing you need to focus on for raiding, and usually, single target DPS is most important. Arcane outshines every other spec for that, but there is slight variations that depends on encounter. [Typical Arcane spec](http://www.wowhead.com/talent#ohIMrRhRMRRofZc:Vs0)

5 Points in Improved Blink and Prismatic Cloak are optional and it could be spread between 4 talents

- Invocation - While seems good, I would not recommend this talent
  because CS has long CD compare to Kick, Pummel etc, and mages are usually not assigned on interrupt duty
- Improved Blink - Very good talent for active player, there is a lot
  of situations where you can gain DPS by simply getting faster to a
  new location as required by encounter.
- Prismatic Cloak - Failsafe, good to have if you are trying to push to
  aggro limit
- Improved Arcane Explosion - Must have for some encounters, completely
  useless for others

Comment: And then you dual spec for heavy AoE fights if needed. not everything can be dealt with via AE

Comment: Care to explain the rotation(s) on the spec you linked? Thanks!